# How to get a recursive ftp directory listing without write permissions?

Tags: command-line, ftp

I know I can run ls * on the ftp server and  get everything, but there's too much for my terminal (hundreds of pages so far). using ls * > myfile isn't an option because I don't have permission to write. So I need a way to do it from the terminal, something like: ftp  ftp://site.com

I've read the man pages but don't want to take a risk here. I don't have personal permission to modify this server but the user I've been given may have write permissions.

I need to export this to any local format so I can review it over time, as there is a *lot* of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](https://superuser.com/a/790257) you can pipe a command directly to `ftp`:

```
echo "ls *" | ftp hostname > ls.txt
```

Make sure to quote `ls *` somehow or to disable globbing otherwise `*` will expand in the current shell.

Comment: Thank you so much! instead of "ls *" I used "ls -R" and indeed I have a full index of the server now.

Answer (score 2):

A good option might be to pipe the output into less:

```
ls * | less
```

Then you should be able to happily scroll through the pages of output without needing any file writing permissions.

Comment: While that would work, the output is so large that I need a way to export it so I can reference it regularly. I'll update my question so that that's clearer. Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing that you can't mount an external drive either. Is there a way to use an FTP client like Filezilla and capture the directory listing from that?

Comment: interesting Arronical! I used Nautilus to connect to the FTP server and from there, right-click -> Open in Terminal (available in the Ubuntu Store). from there I possibly would be able to use the command in your answer if I redirected it to /home/tenleftfingers, but I'm not sure so don't want to risk it :)

I didn't find anything in FileZilla to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
 ncftpls -R ftp://site.com
```

Nice command, designed for exactly this purpose

Answer (score 1):

i've just made a python script for this purpose:
https://gist.github.com/eadmaster/55d1508bd17780ee1e93c15609bb69af

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# code derived from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/flibbertigibbet/8165881/raw/7f580b6735ad1f03c6e6060cd1c8571048afad6a/recurse_ftp.py

from ftplib import FTP
from time import sleep
import os
import sys

my_dirs = []  # global
curdir = ''   # global

PROGRAM_NAME = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

if len(sys.argv) <= 1 or sys.argv[1].startswith("-"):
  print("usage: " + PROGRAM_NAME + " SERVER_ADDR [SERVER_ROOT_DIR]")
  sys.exit(1)
# else
SERVER_ADDR = sys.argv[1]

SERVER_ROOT_PATH = "/"
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
  SERVER_ROOT_PATH = sys.argv[2]

def get_dirs(ln):
  global my_dirs
  cols = ln.split(' ')
  objname = cols[len(cols)-1] # file or directory name
  if ln.startswith('d'):
    my_dirs.append(objname)
  else:
    print(curdir + "/" + objname)

def check_dir(adir):
  global my_dirs
  global curdir
  my_dirs = []
  gotdirs = [] # local
  try:
    curdir = ftp.pwd()
    sys.stderr.write(PROGRAM_NAME + ": going to change to directory " + adir + " from " + curdir + "\n")
    ftp.cwd(adir)
    curdir = ftp.pwd()
    ftp.retrlines('LIST', get_dirs)
  except:
    return
  print(curdir + "/")
  gotdirs = my_dirs
  #print("found in " + adir + " directories:")
  sleep(0.5)
  for subdir in gotdirs:
    if(subdir.startswith(".")):
      continue
    my_dirs = []
    check_dir(subdir) # recurse  
  # end for
  ftp.cwd('..') # back up a directory when done here
# end of check_dir


# main
try:
  ftp = FTP(SERVER_ADDR)
  ftp.login()
  check_dir(SERVER_ROOT_PATH) # directory to start in

except:
  import logging
  logging.exception("")
  ftp.quit()

ftp.quit()
```